# Change system settings email address

Tags: emails, settings

Is there a way to change the email address stored in the `craft_systemsettings` table?

I guess this was originally setup when installing Craft but now I need to change it. I've changed the email address in the user account but this is not modifying the `craft_systemsettings` table. I could go into the phpMyAdmin and modify the MySQL but this feels like quite a clunky process.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to the System Email Address under "Settings" -> "E-mail" -> "System Email Address".

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right! I've clearly not seen that section before.

Comment: If I was right please mark the answer as correct :)